# middleman link_to with image_tag in data files yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, middleman

Can you help me? I dont understand how to combine that.

I have Data File. 
datafile.yml

```
list:
  - title: "Bar"
   desc: "A bar can be classic addition to any home."
   image: "images/bar/1.jpg"
   id: /bar
```

Here is my view:

```
<% data.categories.list.each do |x| %>
<div id="our-work">
    <ul>
        <li><a <%= link_to 'Read more', "#{x.id.to_s}.html"  %> >
        <%= image_tag x.image %>
                <div class="overlay">
                    <summary>
                        <h2><%= x.title %></h2>
                        <h3><%= x.desc %></h3>
                    </summary>
                <div class="nnnext"><span></span></div></div>
            </a>
        </li>
<% end %>
```

I want to create link_to + image tag. in 1 string, how to do it?  i hope you understand what i mean.

image: + id:   => <%= link_to image_tag... %>

link to index.html.erb
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d356271136b1f574965c939a6ba1defb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are not following the syntax especially opening a block and not closing it.

Here is correct structure based on the html you shared.

```
<% data.categories.list.each do |x| %>
  <div id="our-work">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <%= link_to "#{x.id.to_s}.html" do %> 
          <%= image_tag x.image %>
          <div class="overlay">
            <summary>
              <h2><%= x.title %></h2>
              <h3><%= x.desc %></h3>
            </summary>
            <div class="nnnext"><span></span></div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Note: You cannot use text `Read more` when you use `link_to` having block of body which in your case image and other html

Comment: Not work :( /home/lucker/git/kitchen-gallery/source/index.html.erb:46: syntax error, unexpected ')' ore', "#{x.id.to_s}.html" do ).to_s; @_out_buf << ' ^ /home/lucker/git/kitchen-gallery/source/index.html.erb:59: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' '; end ^ /home/lucker/git/kitchen-gallery/source/index.html.erb:113: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')' ensure ^ /home/lucker/git/kitchen-gallery/source/index.html.erb:115: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' end ^

Comment: Can you please update the question and share entire `index.html.erb`?

Comment: question upgraded

Comment: Edited the answer. I have tested the html locally, it works fine now.

Comment: idn. its still not work... that... here is full error : 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6f34ed0fe13b1a6d792e500b0971dcc8

Comment: Can you tell me what is the role of middleman in your rails app?